# why my function for change the player doesn't work please?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I'm beginner and I've create a dice play.
there is a button to reserve the score.
When I click on this button the current score of the active player come back to 0 and, usually, the active player change .
When active player change, there is a switch function who change variables.
My button is ok, my function to switch variables is ok.
My problem is my function to switch player, I don't understand why she doesn't work...

```
const roll = document.getElementById("roll");

//function to switch between players
function switchPlayer () {
  if (activePlayer === 'player 1') {
    activePlayer = 'player 2';
    console.log("passe au 2eme player")
  } else {
    activePlayer = 'player 1';
    console.log("passe au 1er player")
  }
}

//function to change variables according to the players
switch (activePlayer) {
  case 'player 1': {
    var currentText = document.getElementById("currentScore");
    var reserveText = document.getElementById("reserveScore");
    var current = currentScore;
    var reserved = reserveScore;
    break;
  }
  case 'player 2': {
    var currentText = document.getElementById("currentScore2");
    var reserveText = document.getElementById("reserveScore2");
    var current = currentScore2;
    var reserved = reserveScore2;
    break;
  }
  default: {
    console.log('erreur de sélection de joueur');
  }
}

//function to add current score to your score if you click on "reserver" and change player.
function reserve() {
  reserved += current;
  reserveText.textContent = reserved;
  current = 0;
  if (reserved >= 100){
    status.innerHTML = winMessage();
  };
  switchPlayer();
  currentText.textContent = 0;
}

//here we call functions
hold.addEventListener("click", reserve);
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `function switchPlayer (activePlayer)`, if you have an outer scoped variable named `activePlayer` your function won't change it as it is just changing the local variable, change the names or dont have the  function parameter at all since you dont seem to be passing it in anyway `switchPlayer();`

Comment: I have do research in related topics but don't found my answer sorry

Comment: thank you @PatrickEvans , the player change with your help, but my function to change variables according to the players does not take into account this change while I checked it works if I change manually "let activePlayer = 'player 1';" to "let activePlayer = 'player 2';"